# Append to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a csv file that has numbers integers and floats,

```
"5",7.30124705657363,2,12,7.45176205440562
"18",6.83169608190656,5,11,7.18118108407457
"20",6.40446470770985,4,10,6.70549470337383
"3",5.37498781178147,17,9,5.9902122724706
"10",5.12954203598201,8,8,5.58108702947798
"9",3.93496153596789,7,7,4.35751055597501
```

I am doing some arithmetic and then I am trying to add them into a dictionary but I am getting key error. Here is the code that I have,

```
global oldPriceCompRankDict
oldPriceCompRankDict = {}

def increaseQuantityByOne(self, fileLocation):
    rows = csv.reader(open(fileLocation))
    rows.next()
    print "PricePercentage\t" + "OldQuantity\t" + "newQuantity\t" + "oldCompScore\t" + "newCompScore"
    for row in rows:
        newQuantity = float(row[2]) + 1.0
        newCompetitiveScore = float(row[1]) + float(math.log(float(newQuantity), 100))
        print row[1] + "\t", str(row[2])+"\t", str(newQuantity) + "\t", str(row[4]) + "\t", newCompetitiveScore
        oldPriceCompRankDict[row[3]].append(row[4])
```

I have un-ordered key, and I didn't think the key has to be in an ordered format. I thought anything could be key.

Comment: When you get a Python traceback, please share it so people answering do not have to go hunting in your code where the error may have been coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to put in the `global` keyword, it's a no-op.
Use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

oldPriceCompRankDict = defaultdict(list)
```

What is happening is that you never define any keys for `oldPriceCompRankDict`, you just expect them to be lists by default. The `defaultdict` type gives you a dict that does just that; when a key is not yet found in `oldPriceCompRankDict` a new `list()` instance will be used as the starting value instead of raising a KeyError.

Comment: I also resolved the issue by  oldPriceCompRankDict[row[3]] = row[4] is this a good practice?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: In that case at least you are assigning a new key/value to your dict, yes. If that's what you want instead of having a dict of lists, that's just fine. :-)

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: Let's not use SO comments as a support forum; better search SO for possible answers and/or create a new question (after you tried some things).

Answer (score 2):

A Python dictionary type does not have an `append()` method. What you are doing is basically trying to call an `append()` method of the dictionary element accessible by key `row[3]`. You get a `KeyError` because you have nothing under key `row[3]`.

You should substitute your code

```
oldPriceCompRankDict[row[3]].append(row[4])
```

for this:

```
oldPriceCompRankDict[row[3]] = row[4]
```

In addition, the `global` keyword is used inside functions to indicate that variable is a global one, you can read about it here: [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)
so the right way to declare a global dictionary would be just `oldPriceCompRankDict = {}`

Your function will start adding to the dictionary from the second row because you call `rows.next()` if it is a desirable behavior then it's OK, otherwise you don't need to call that method.

Hope this was helpful, happy coding!